# How to change background color of buttons on button click?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am begging of angular and MVC developer,

I am using two html buttons, its default background color is 'RED',
when I click button1 its change background color is 'Green' in button1 and button2 its 'Blue'.

Here by code,

```
<button id="outer" style="background-color:red">BUTTON1</button>
<button class="btn-5" id="outer" style="background-color:red">BUTTON2</button>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: https://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/xtbzc checkthis for ng class

Comment: My output its if i click button1, it will be change button1 background color its 'green' at the same time button2 its 'Blue'

Answer (score 0):

we can simple use ng-class

```
<button id="outer" style="background-color:red" ng-class="{background-color:green:changebgColor}" ng-click="changebgColor=!changebgColor">BUTTON1</button>
<button class="btn-5" id="outer" style="background-color:red" ng-class="{background-color:blue:changebgColor}">BUTTON2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run code in the snippet to see the result.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

  app.controller("con",function($scope){
    $scope.class1 = "red";
    $scope.class2 = "red";
    $scope.changeClass = function(){     
        $scope.class1 = "green";     
        $scope.class2 = "blue";  
        };
  });
```

```css
.green{
    background-color:green;
  }
  .blue{
    background-color:blue;
  }
  .red{
    background-color:red;
  }
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="con">
<button id="outer" ng-class="class1" ng-click="changeClass()">BUTTON1</button>
<button id="outer" ng-class="class2" ng-click="changeClass()">BUTTON2</button>
</body>
```